# rpath issues in manifest.xml:

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I came across with problem when I tried to install segway_rmp under the instructions http://www.ros.org/wiki/segway_rmp,

but it displays:
ERROR The following packages have rpath issues in manifest.xml:

- segway_rmp_demos: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
- segway_rmpX: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
- joy2twist_segway_rmp: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"

Thank you for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39711/rpath-issues-in-manifest.xml:/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2012-07-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on 2012-08-09**:
I came with the same problem too!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess it's not been updated for fuerte, yet.

Similar issues: http://answers.ros.org/question/38026/roswtf-and-rpath-problems-in-fuerte/

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0